# GitLab CI: combine rules and only

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a .gitlab-ci.yml file that has defined triggers and inside them I defined a rules that this build is only fired when there is a change, but I want also this to be fired when the branch is develop. It looks like this:

```
stages:
  - triggers

# Trigger 1
trigger_1:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: path/to/1/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - changes:
        - path/to/1/*

# Trigger 2
trigger_2:
  stage: triggers
  trigger:
    include:
      - local: path/to/2/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
    - changes:
        - path/to/2/*
```

I cannot figure out how do I add `only` or define different `rules` and what rule to use. How can I add the rule that when the branch is `develop` always trigger all jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Just add another rule in addition to the `changes:` rule.

```yaml
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
    - changes:
      - path/to/1/*
```

The rules are combined like a logical OR statement.